# how to take some columns from a database in R

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I want from a database to take a few columns and use it in R.

```
require(RODBC)
ch <- odbcConnect("ims")
```

so now i am connected to the database

i have many tables and i want to take only one so:

```
ress <- sqlFetch(ch, "Fact_GPIM")
```

and last i have some columns and i want to take only few rows, cause there are too many rows, so i think to use a Query:

```
y<-sqlQuery(ch, paste("select ress[[5]] from ress","where ress[[5]]=0549604"))
```

but i do something wrong and i don't know what. this is the text that appears

```
    > y
[1] "42000 105 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[5] from ress where ress[[5]=0549604'."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select ress[[5]] from ress where ress[[5]]=0549604'"
```

what i do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to pull a few values from the 5th column? Try something like `select [name of 5th column] from ress where [name of 5th column] = 0549604;`, or if you want just a few values why not use a limit?: `select [column] from ress limit 100;`.

Comment: What are the names of the columns you would like to return? What is the name of the table you are querying? Which is the column whose value should equal `'0549604'`?

Comment: when i get the "Fact_GPIM" (table) from the database i also write ress <- sqlFetch(ch, "Fact_GPIM",colnames=TRUE). Then i write colnames(ress) and i dont get any column name but instead i get numbers(the first row of the table)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".